# Visio: Setting connectors or relationships with Excel data source

Tags: visio, visio2013

I'm able to import objects into a diagram from Excel without a problem; however, I also want to define connections (just lines - what object the line starts from, and what object it goes to) in Excel as well, so I don't have to draw them manually.

How do I go about doing this? How should I define that in my Excel spreadsheet, and how should I import those relationships into Visio?

I'm on Visio 2013 Professional.

Comment: Wrong stackexchange site.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure which other stackexchange community to post this on; what would be your suggestion?

Comment: Try superuser.com Or, better, http://visguy.com. Anyways there is no good solution to your question. Visio does not provide auto-generation functionality. Although this feature is requested quite frequently.